# CPython string addition optimisation failure case

Tags: python, string, optimization, cpython

## The Question

Why, in CPython, does

```
def add_string(n):
    s = ''
    for _ in range(n):
        s += ' '
```

take linear time, but

```
def add_string_in_list(n):
    l = ['']
    for _ in range(n):
        l[0] += ' '
```

take quadratic time?

---

Proof:

```
Timer(partial(add_string, 1000000)).timeit(1)
#>>> 0.1848409200028982
Timer(partial(add_string, 10000000)).timeit(1)
#>>> 1.1123797750042286
```

```
Timer(partial(add_string_in_list, 10000)).timeit(1)
#>>> 0.0033865350123960525
Timer(partial(add_string_in_list, 100000)).timeit(1)
#>>> 0.25131178900483064
```

---

## What I know

CPython has an optimisation for string addition when the string being added to has a reference count of 1.

This is because strings in Python are immutable, and so normally they cannot be edited. If multiple references exist to a string and it is mutated, *both* references will see the changed string. This is obviously not wanted, so mutation cannot happen with multiple references.

If there is only one reference to the string, however, mutating the value will only change the string for that one reference, which wants it changed. You can test that this is a likely cause as so:

```
from timeit import Timer
from functools import partial

def add_string_two_references(n):
    s = ''
    for _ in range(n):
        s2 = s
        s += ' '

Timer(partial(add_string_two_references, 20000)).timeit(1)
#>>> 0.032532954995986074
Timer(partial(add_string_two_references, 200000)).timeit(1)
#>>> 1.0898985149979126
```

I'm unsure why the factor is only 30x, instead of the expected 100x, but I believe that it's overhead.

---

## What I don't know

So why is the list version creating two references? Is this even what's preventing the optimisation?

You can check that it's not treating normal objects any differently:

```
class Counter:
    def __iadd__(self, other):
        print(sys.getrefcount(self))

s = Counter()
s += None
#>>> 6

class Counter:
    def __iadd__(self, other):
        print(sys.getrefcount(self))

l = [Counter()]
l[0] += None
#>>> 6
```

Comment: "If multiple references exist to a string and it changes, both references will see the changed string." That's not true.

Comment: "it changes" ≜ "is mutated"; I'll fix the wording. // Fixed.

Comment: No. `x = 'a'; y = x; x = 'b'` - and `y` still holds 'a'. The same for `x = 'a'; y = x; x += 'b'`

Comment: I agree. But the string isn't mutated *in that case*. CPython only mutates strings when it is safe to (when there is only one reference); otherwise `y` *would* change, which is bad.

Comment: Even though `+=` is a special partially optimised case, the recommended way is to use `.join()`, that is guaranteed to be optimised across implementations, and will receive all the love from the developers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the list based approach, string from index 0 of the list is taken and modified before being put back to the list at index 0.
For this short moment interpreter still has the old version of string in the list and can't perform in place modification.
If you take a look at [Python's source](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c) then you'll see that there is no support for modifying the element of the list in place. So the object (string in this case) has to be retrieved from the list, modified and then put back.
In other words `list` type is completely agnostic of the `str` type support for `+=` operator.

And consider the following code:

```
l = ['abc', 'def']
def nasty():
    global l
    l[0] = 'ghi'
    l[1] = 'jkl'
    return 'mno'
l[0] += nasty()
```

The value of `l` is `['abcmno', 'jkl']` which proves that `'abc'` was taken from the list, then `nasty()` got executed modifying the contents of the list, strings `'abc'` and `'mno'` got concatenated and result was assigned to `l[0]`. If `nasty()` was evaluated before accessing `l[0]` to modify it in place, then the result would be `'ghimno'`.

Answer (score 6):

> So why is the list version creating two references?

In `l[0] += ' '`, one reference is in `l[0]`. One reference is created temporarily to perform the `+=` on.

Here are two simpler functions to show the effect:

```
>>> def f():
...     l = ['']
...     l[0] += ' '
...     
>>> def g():
...     s = ''
...     s += ' '
...
```

Disassembling them gives

```
>>> from dis import dis
>>> dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('')
              3 BUILD_LIST               1
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (l)

  3           9 LOAD_FAST                0 (l)
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
             15 DUP_TOPX                 2
             18 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             19 LOAD_CONST               3 (' ')
             22 INPLACE_ADD         
             23 ROT_THREE           
             24 STORE_SUBSCR        
             25 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             28 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis(g)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('')
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (s)

  3           6 LOAD_FAST                0 (s)
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 (' ')
             12 INPLACE_ADD         
             13 STORE_FAST               0 (s)
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             19 RETURN_VALUE
```

In `f`, the [`BINARY_SUBSCR`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-BINARY_SUBSCR) (slicing) instruction puts `l[0]` at the top of the VM stack. [`DUP_TOPX`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-DUP_TOPX) duplicates the top *n* items on the stack. Both functions (see [`ceval.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/09b33fc96a50/Python/ceval.c)) increase the reference count; `DUP_TOPX` (`DUP_TOP_TWO` in Py3) does it directly, while `BINARY_SUBSCR` uses [`PyObject_GetItem`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html#PyObject_GetItem). So, the reference count of the string is now at least three.

`g` doesn't have this problem. It creates one additional reference when the item is pushed with `LOAD_FAST`, giving a refcount of two, the minimal number for an item on the VM stack, so it can do the optimization.

Comment: +1 I had the same answer, but took much longer to write it up :)

Comment: @chepner I was surprised to see you come up with exactly the same test functions -- except your `g` is my `f` and your `f  is my `g` :)

Comment: +1 for your answer. The code in my answer proves exactly the same as your disassembling output.

Comment: Thanks very much. I wasn't expecting `DUP_TOP_TWO` to increase the refcount. Also, many thanks for the source links, which are always nice.

Comment: I think I'm going to give the accept to ElmoVanKielmo, but you both deserve it really :).