# Why is addition of immutable containers in a loop O(n²)?

Tags: performance, language-agnostic, big-o

I have heard that adding immutable strings, or other immutable (contiguous) containers of multiple items, in a loop can be `O(n²)`. For example

```
string = ""
repeat n times:
    string = string + "X"
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding an immutable contiguous container of length `A` to one of length `B` normally takes `O(A+B)` time. This is because the resulting container will need to be built anew, and is of length `A+B`.

Consider the `i`th addition of the given loop. The string will be of length `i-1`, and you add a string of length `1`. The resulting string, and thus the time required, is therefore proportional to `i`.

We therefore have the total cost:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + ... + n-2 + n-1 + n

= ∑i from i=1 to i=n

= ½n·(n+1)

= ½n² + ½n
```

which is of the order `O(n²)`.

---

The reason these are specified as *contiguous* containers is because *some* non-contiguous immutable containers (like binary trees) can merely reference the other immutable containers instead of copying them, which can increase the speed of addition.