# How to speed up nested for loop without import any function

Tags: performance, python-3.x, for-loop, matrix

How can I reduce processing time of nested loops without import any function? My program is pretty fast, but it took very long to write the matrix. I tried using `range` 
and other suggestion I found online, but it's still the same.

```
for i in matrix:
    string = ''
    for j in i:
        if j not in path and j != 'N':
             string += '_'
        elif j in path and j != 'N':
             string += '+'
        else:
             string += 'N'
f.write(string+"\n")
```

Thank you

Comment: What is `path`? If it is something that could be a `set` it should make it faster for start.

Comment: What do `matrix` and `path` contain? Building up a string by repeated concatenation is generally pretty bad; membership testing in non-hash-based containers is also slow.

Comment: Thank you zipa, yes I used set and it helped a lot

Comment: Don't use `+=` on strings in loops! It might *seem* fast, but [it has trivial failure cases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040198/cpython-string-addition-optimisation-failure-case) and generally can't be relied upon. Make a list and call `join`, like @tzaman showed.

Comment: Hi Veedrac, thank you so much for letting me know! I have a wrong impression that += aString is more faster, so I almost use it for my every program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `path` is a string or list you could convert it into a set for faster lookups:

```
path_set = set(path)
```

Next, you can avoid repeated string concatenation using the `join` function combined with a generator expression:

```
output = ''.join('N' if j=='N' else '+' if j in path_set else '_' 
                 for i in matrix 
                 for j in i)
```

Also note that by reordering the conditions, you can avoid having to do the `path` test twice; also, by checking for `'N'` first (which is far cheaper), you can sometimes skip it entirely.

Comment: Hi tzaman, Yes! You are right, path is a list. Thank you so much for this excellent expression, it is totally new to me. I slightly modified it to fit in my program and it took only 3 secs. Thanks again!!